# python program to find value of 4**4**4**4 or 4**4**256

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

This number is too big to run it directly in ipython console. I have no idea how to do it but it can be done as a big number calculator online and they check big prime numbers while running decryption algorithm on laptop. Any help is apreciated.

Comment: Check out the bignum library see docs here [BigNumber 1](https://pypi.org/project/BigNumber/)

Answer (score -2):

```
print(pow(256,256))  '''output - 21095088152386448283120630877367300996091750197750389652106796057638384067568276792218642619756161838094338476170470581645852036305042887575891541065808607552399123930385521914333389668342420684974786564569494856176035326322058077805659331026192708460314150258592864177116725943603718461857357598351152301645904403697613233287231227125684710820209725157101726931323469678542580656697935045997268352998638215525166389437335543602135433229604645318478604952148193555853611059596230656'''
```